# Undefined method `image' for #<ActiveStorage::Attachment:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods, dropzone.js, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to implement photo upload using DropzoneJS and Active Storage but at this point, my app throws `undefined method 'image' for #<ActiveStorage::Attachment:0x00007fa51201dd80>` error.

[image]

**models/car.rb**

[image]

**index.html.erb**

[image]

[image]

My Gemfile. Do i need to uncomment image-processing gem to enable and use?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
#gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  #Provides better error page for Rails and other Rack apss.
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.5', '>= 2.5.1'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.4.1'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.9'

gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 5.0'

#new gems
group :development, :production do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4', github: 'capistrano/rbenv', require: false
end
#gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.11'
#gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
#gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
#gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

This is a bit confusing as i'm new to this.

Am i suppose to create a Controller for `Photos`?

Do i need to add a certain gem too?

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create another model. All you need to make sure you add `has_many_attached :photos` to your model file and using `url_for(self.photos[0])` for getting url. You can also go with `self.photos[0].service_url`

Edit after comments:

You are getting same NoMethodError because there is no image method defined on cover_photo. One way of correcting your can be like this

```rb
def cover_photo(size_x, size_y)
  if self.photos.length > 0
    self.photos[0].variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed.service_url
  else
    "blank.jpg"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i already have `has_many_attached :photos` in my car.rb model

Comment: Please can you explain how exactly i should do it? Because it doesn't work, i'm still getting the error.

Comment: Can you share the error message? It can be related with sizing. In order to get images with a size variant need to be used. (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html)

Comment: It's a NoMethodError `undefined method `image' for #<ActiveStorage::Attachment:`. I have edited the question, added my gemfile so you may have a look if i need to add a gem.

Comment: I edited my answer. It can help you to solve the problem

Comment: I used the same code in your answer but now i'm getting the error `ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2):
  app/models/car.rb:13:in 'cover_photo'`

Comment: Change your all ```<%= image_tag car.cover_photo(:thumb) %>``` to ```<%= image_tag car.cover_photo(75,100) %>```

Comment: Okay, done that but this is what i get now `DEPRECATION WARNING: Generating image variants will require the image_processing gem in Rails 6.1. Please add 'gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2' to your Gemfile. (called from cover_photo at /home/maxxx/my_proj/app/models/car.rb:15)
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 35.0ms | Allocations: 6742)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 7799)



Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan - :`

Comment: Added `image_processing` gem and proceeded with installing Image-magick. Now it throws the error `bad URI(is not URI?): nil`. Btw, i have also updated the question; i meant to say if i'm supposed to create a `Controller` for `Photo` rather and not model.

Comment: I've followed most tutorials but the `bad URI(is not URI?): nil` error still persists. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Can you copy and paste your latest code with ```image_processing``` gem?

Comment: How so please? i only added the gem

Comment: Did you check the gem page about the error you get? https://github.com/janko/image_processing

Comment: Yes, found nothing helpful on the gem page about the error

Comment: I have fixed it. I removed `.service_url` from `self.photos[0].variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed.service_url` so it became `self.photos[0].variant(resize_to_limit: [size_x, size_y]).processed`. I just don't why it works this way. Can you explain pls, if you know why?